# AWS Lambda/DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My Lambda is invoking other lambda, First lambda will be inserting the data into DynamoDB from S3 and second lambda get invoked. The second lambda will read the data from DynamoDb and create excel file in S3.
While inserting 100's records it worked good but while inserting 1500 + records, the first lambda is inserting the data correctly into DynamoDb and invoking the second lambda but the second lambda creates two files, one with correct number of records which expected and the other one is duplicated with less number than expected.

I tried increasing the time out for both lambda but did not work.

Comment: Is one Lambda directly invoking the other or is the 1st Lambda simply inserting items into DynamoDB while DynamoDB Streams is triggering the 2nd Lambda?

Comment: The first lambda is inserting into dynamoDB and triggering the 2nd lambda as well that will reads the data from DynamoDB

Comment: So, Lambda #1 writes N items to DynamoDB and then synchronously (or asynchronously?) invokes Lambda #2, sending it the list of keys for the newly-written DynamoDB items?

Comment: How does Lambda 2 know which rows to insert into the file? Does it insert _ALL_ rows, and then delete them from DynamoDB, or is there some other way for it to know which rows to insert?

Answer (score 0):

While i am not sure why your code will generate duplicate excels, i want to give some insights on application/architecture perspectives:

Why you need to insert something to ddb first, then use another process to read data back from ddb to generate excels? It seems to me the process can be done in a single lambda, that the lambda function read data from source S3 into local tmp directory or memory of lambda, and then insert data the ddb, and then use the local data to generate the excels in target S3.